# The server and client components in Vercel Next JS have different timezones

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, vercel

In my Next.js 13.2.4 application, I have a helper function called `getLocalTime(date)` that returns the local time of the client machine in a specific format.

```
//Output format: 9:30PM
export function getLocalTime(date) {

  const localTime = new Date(date).toLocaleTimeString("en-US", {
    hour: "numeric",
    minute: "numeric",
    hour12: true,
    timezone: Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone,
  });

  return localTime;
}
```

When I run the application locally using `npm run dev`, the function returns the correct time relative to my local time. However, when I deployed the application to Vercel, I noticed that the server components are using the UTC timezone, while the client components are using the actual timezone of the user.

So I tried to hardcode the timezone like this.

```
//Output format: 9:30PM
export function getLocalTime(date) {
  const BucharestTimezone = "Europe/Bucharest";

  const localTime = new Date(date).toLocaleTimeString("en-US", {
    hour: "numeric",
    minute: "numeric",
    hour12: true,
    timezone: BucharestTimezone,
  });

  return localTime;
}
```

But the problem stayed the same.

My question is: how can I make sure that the server components in Next.js use the timezone of the client machine, rather than UTC?

Comment: Have you considered using this: https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/usage/configuration?

Comment: Thank you for the response, I tried the library but it still doesn't fully support Next JS 13. I tried to follow the new instructions to implement the TimeZone feature for Next 13, but no effects were seen. It's frustrating that I'm not able to modify something this simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by using [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/?id=luxon) or [date-fns-tz](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns-tz) libraries.

In the end, I opted to use date-fns-tz since it requires less code refactoring for me.

#### Solution 1: using date-fns-tz

```
import { utcToZonedTime } from "date-fns-tz";
    
export function getLocalTime(date) {
      const localTime = utcToZonedTime(
        new Date(date),
        "Europe/Bucharest"
      ).toLocaleTimeString("en-US", {
        hour: "numeric",
        minute: "numeric",
        hour12: true,
      });
    
  return localTime;  //Output format: 9:30 PM
}
```

here I used `utcToZonedTime` to convert the time to UTC for both the client and server components, then for its second argument I would specify a timezone I would like the time to be in. ex: `Europe/Bucharest`

#### Solution 2: using Luxon

```
import { DateTime } from "luxon";

export function getLocalTime(date) {
 
  const localTime =  DateTime.fromISO(date, { zone: "utc" }).setZone(
    "Europe/Bucharest"
  ).toFormat("h:mm a");

  return localTime; //Output format: 9:30 PM
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Next.js server components use the UTC timezone. you can try moment.js. as moment js will always return time according to the client device timezone. link for reference.  [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Considering using Moment in your project?
There may be better modern alternatives.
For more details and recommendations,
please see Project Status in the docs.